# Как такой текст привести в ассоциативный массив?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите с регулярным выражением или может еще что, чтобы сделать массив вида:

```
[Имя актрисы] => Ромашка
[Подсайт и сайт] => rospotrebnadzor.ru
[Год производства] => 1997 г.
```

итд. В данном примере встречаются разные строки разделенные переносом строки и без. Я пробовал разбивать текст построчно и каждую строку разделять символами ' : ' но в данном случае это не работает т.к. в некоторых строках после ' :' - пусто (след. элемент массива).

```
Незнайка на луне
Имя актрисы :
Ромашка
Подсайт и сайт :
rospotrebnadzor.ru
Год производства : 1997 г.
Жанр :
Комедия Семейное
Продолжительность : 00:45:18
Описание :
Во время уборки урожая Незнайка решает лично принести арбуз и
только чудом спасается от него. Решив в качестве извинения принести
огурец, Незнайка ночью отправляется в огород, где
сталкивается с майским жуком, которого ему удаётся напугать своей
тенью. Но затем жук понимает, что был обманут, и налетает на
Незнайку сзади, ударив его по голове, после чего улетает.
Формат видео : MP4
Видео : H.264/AVC 720х400 16/9 29970 fps 1800 kbps
Аудио : AAC Dolby Digital, 44.1Hz, 2ch, 128 kbps
```

Comment: что вы пробовали сделать, и что не получилось?

Comment: @splash58, Я пробовал разбивать текст построчно и каждую строку разделять символами ' : ' но в данном случае это не работает т.к. в некоторых строках после ' :' - пусто (след. элемент массива).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Разбиваете текст с помощью регулярки с сохранением ключей
2. добвляете ведущий ключ "название"
3. делите массив на пары элементов
4. первый элемент пары делаете ключом, второй значением.

---

```
$data = preg_split("/^(.+?) :/m", $txt, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

array_unshift($data, 'title');
$data = array_chunk($data, 2);

$result = [];


foreach($data as list($k, $v)){
    $result[$k] = trim($v);
}

// вариант c array_walk
// array_walk($data, function($p) use(&$result){.
//                       list($k, $v) = $p;
//                       $result[$k] = trim($v);
//                   });


print_r($result);
```

---

*зы: не сразу прочитал контент текста. не первый раз вы постите подобный контент, и лучше бы вам его заменять на что-нибудь более обыденное, подобный текст не уместен на данном ресурсе. так что лучше замените текст на описание какого-нибудь "Незнайки на луне"*

Comment: Да ладно Вам, когда я начал жаловаться на подобный контент, мне намекнули, что какая разница, вопрос то технический))

Comment: @DaemonHK это то понятно.

Comment: @teran, Спасибо! В будущем буду "шифровать" данные))